# How to trap an error that is destroying a .NET session?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a .NET 4.5 website where my Session is occasionally disappearing (which, because of my login setup, forces a re-login).

I'm suspecting there is an un-caught error that is killing the Session, but allowing execution to otherwise continue.

My web.config contains the following vanilla-variety sessionState element...

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How can I best go about identifying what is causing the Session to dump, given that there is no visible error message or other bad behavior from the application?

Comment: Uncaught exceptions do not kill the session. Are you making any changes in the web site around the time you lose the session? And is this an actual web site "project" (file->New Web Site), or a web application project (file->New Project)?

Comment: I'm on a Mac (strange, I know, but .NET isn't my main thing) and am not using Visual Studio to create or edit this project, so I'm not sure if in VS terminology this is a "New Web Site" or a "New Project," but I believe the former.  Often times these session-deaths will occur as I'm making changes (although it seems this is not the only time they happen).  I'm interested in the relevance of this question, though... Can you elaborate?

Comment: "as I'm making changes".. some changes (i.e. change to web.config) cause an Application Restart (and Session death, of course)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEW ANSWER

"as I'm making changes".. some changes (i.e. change to web.config) cause an Application Restart (and Session death, of course)!
[Look here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx)

> if you're running in-process session state, then obviously it's going
>   to be reset each and every time the application pool is recycled.

Application restarts for:
 - Recycle worker processes (in minutes)
 - Recycle worker process (in requests)
 - Recycle worker processes at the following times
 - Maximum virtual memory
 - Maximum used memory
 - memoryLimit
 - requestLimit
 - timeout
 - **Editing and updating**
     -- **web.config**
  -- **machine.config**
  -- **global.asax**
 -- **Anything in the bin directory or it's sub-directories**

"A workaround to the sub-directory issue", read it.

---

OLD ANSWER

Error won't easily kill session even if they're un-caught..

- maybe you're facing problems related to page life-cycle (You should be able to access the Session in or after the Page's OnInit event)
- or you're facing problems on multi session elements (flash-based file uploader can open a different session)
- or you have installed on multiple server your application (each server has his own session!)

could be one of these?

Comment: Normal actions to access the Session work fine.  (The whole application is using the Session to manage, among other things, the logged-in user's identity.) There are no fancy file uploaders here, nor is the application spread over multiple servers.

Comment: Can you post some code to address suggestions for useful help?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this accounts for all the session-deaths, but the /App_Code changes might be the culprit.  I knew about web.config causing an application restart, but /App_Code is new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm suspecting there is an un-caught error that is killing the Session
```

In Visual Studio:

Debug **->** Exceptions... **->** Common Language Runtime Exceptions **->** Check the 2 check boxes.

This way, you'll be able to *break on* any `exception`.